# Hadoop and Cassandra processing rows in sorted order

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

I want to fill a Cassandra database with a list of strings that I then process using Hadoop. What I want to do it run through all the strings in order using a Hadoop cluster and record how much overlap there is between each string in order to find the Longest Common Substring.

My question is, will the InputFormat object allow me to read out the data in a sorted order or will my strings be read out "randomly" (according to how Cassandra decides to distribute them) throughout every machine in the cluster? Is the MapReduce process designed to process each row by itself w/out the intent of looking at two rows consecutively like I'm asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the Mappers will read the data in whatever order they get it from the InputFormat. I'm not a Cassandra expert, but I don't expect that will be in sorted order.

If you want sorted order, you should use an identity mapper (one that does nothing) whose output key is the string itself. Then they will be sorted before passed to the reduce step. But it gets a little more complicated since you can have more than one reducer. With only one reducer, everything is globally sorted. With more than one, each reducer's input is sorted, but the input across reducers might not be sorted. That is, adjacent strings might not go to the same reducer. You would need a custom partitioner to handle that.

Lastly, you mentioned that you're doing longest common substring- are you looking for the longest substring among each pair of strings? Among consecutive pairs of strings? Among all strings? Each of these possibilities will affect how you need to structure your MapReduce job.